# Add segmentController on Navigation Bar through xib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Can any one please tell me how to add segmentController on Navigation Bar Using xib but not using storyboards ? And its for iphone only not for ipad.

Comment: which Xcode are you using? I am using Xcode 4.4.1 and i can easily adding segmentControl on navigationBar using xib.

Answer (score 2):

Drag UIToolBar at the top of your XIB..Then Drag UIsegmentControl on it..This way u shall get a custom navigationBar..

if the default iphone navigationBar shows up..add the following code in its viewWillAppear

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

Comment: In storyboards, if you directly drag segmentController on naviagation bar. it will come directly. So, in the same way is it possible without Storyboards

Answer (score 2):

Go through this link once.This may give an idea.

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=rk1EEL4WpFEC&pg=PA504&lpg=PA504&dq=Add+segment+Controller+in+Navigation+Bar+through+xib+%2B+iphone+sdk&source=bl&ots=KVUnDOmKA6&sig=wPiJj18ZVCgCp_ScZ7m0o4Ou-H4&hl=en#v=onepage&q=Add%20segment%20Controller%20in%20Navigation%20Bar%20through%20xib%20%2B%20iphone%20sdk&f=false